# How can I control all my website's requests?

Tags: web-application, php

I need to manage my website's requests. Because of both I need to detect suspect requests and block that IP and calculate the number of users which visit my website.

So I've created a table like this:

```
// requests
+----+----------------+-------------+
| id |  UserId_or_IP  |  unix_time  |
+----+----------------+-------------+
| 1  | 12353          | 1339412843  |
| 2  | 23353          | 1339412864  |
| 3  | 178.253.29.175 | 1339412894  |
| 4  | 3422           | 1339412899  |
| 5  | 342232         | 1339412906  |
| 6  | 2353           | 1339412906  |
| 7  | 7785           | 1339412951  |
| 8  | 148.23.29.109  | 1339413640  |
| 9  | 178.253.29.175 | 1339413621  |
| 10 | 5462           | 1339414490  |
| 11 | 342232         | 1339414923  |
| 12 | 178.253.29.175 | 1339419901  |
| 13 | 8007           | 1339424860  |
| 14 | 8007           | 1339424822  |
| 15 | 2353           | 1339424902  |
+----+----------------+-------------+
```

And I insert a new row into that table for every request *(opening every page of my website means one request)*.

And here is my query in the `index.php`: *(`index.php` is a page which all pages pass from it)*

```
INSERT INTO requests (id, UserId_or_IP, unix_time)
            VALUES   (NULL, :id_or_ip, UNIX_TIME());
```

---

**All I need to know:** What I'm doing is correct or there is a better approach to control requests? As you know That query makes my webpage-loading slow *(a bit)*, because there is an `INSERT` query before loading every page. Well has it worth? In fact I'm trying to understand what's the standard way for doing that.

Comment: how is recording the ID\IP a method of controlling requests?

Comment: @schroeder I have a query which calculates the number of all requests from a constant ID/IP per day.. So if that number is huge, then I will block it.

Comment: ok - so when you say "suspect requests" you really mean "high volumes of requests from a single source". The one problem with your plan is shared IPs. If a large company is accessing your site, you will end up with what looks like high volume from a single source. Unless you have other method determining "suspicious requests" you might have to plan for high volumes.

Comment: @schroeder Ok you are right .. You know, I asked that question because I need to know how should I do that exactly? I know my plan isn't perfect. So what's the standard way? How a website like SE manages requests? How it determines suspect requests?

Comment: They do what I mention: they plan for capacity and define what "suspicious" means to them.

Comment: Why do you care that you might get lots of visitors? Is that not a good thing? Are you hitting resource limits? Cost limits?

Comment: @Matthew Lots of visitors **is** a good thing, but when a constant user visits all my website's pages based on a specific order, that means he is a robot which is spying my website's content.

Comment: Or a web crawler, getting your content into search engines, or a user who really likes your content and wants to read it all... You've put the content on your website - surely you want it to be read?

Comment: @Matthew `:-)` .. Yeah I'm sure about it .. But I don't want somebody spy my valuable databases and create a similar website like mine.

Comment: @stack any website is public, and anyone can copy it. If that's what you want to prevent, then you need to approach the problem *very* differently.

Comment: @schroeder Alright .. May you please tell me what's the meaning of *"a suspect request"*? And do I need to control requests? *(is there any reason?)*

Comment: A suspect request is one that indicates non-usual behaviour that might be linked to unwanted behaviour. What that means for you will be unique. Whether or not you need to rate-limit requests is a question for your app and what your servers can handle.

Comment: Use mod_security with rate-limiting. Why re-invent wheels? https://johnleach.co.uk/words/1073/rate-limiting-with-apache-and-mod-security

Comment: @munkeyoto thx, but I'm using nginx not apache.

Comment: @stack what are you running? That would definitely help get a better answer

Comment: @munkeyoto What do you mean *"running"*? (sorry I don't know English very well)

Comment: @stack running = using. What webserver are you using, on what platform?

Comment: @munkeyoto I'm using nginx ..!

Comment: @stack same rules as my initial comment apply just add it to NGINX https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-nginx-with-mod_security-on-ubuntu-15-04/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In fact I'm trying to understand what's the standard way for doing that.

On a properly configured web server, the web server will log all received requests in a log file (the exact content of this log file is usually more or less configurable, depending on the server software used). There are also standard means to centralize the logs if you want to like [syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) which will allow you to store and analyze the logs on a different machine.

The content of this log can then be analyzed by external software in order to either:

- Generate statistics, there are plenty of monitoring software depending on your exact software and needs,
- Detect suspicious behavior, here you will search for IDS / IPS software, depending if you need Detection only (IDS), or Protection too (IPS). [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) for instance is a classical example of such software for Linux/Unix platforms: it will monitor your server log files, detect suspicious behavior according to some set of rules and optionally trigger an action (send an alert email or update firewall rules to ban the offender for instance).

You did not asked for it in your question, but speaking of standard practice, generally the logs are also analyzed in order to analyze the health of the server software and detect possible issues and outage. As for IDS/IPS, you have the option to have a simple detection & alert system or automatic actions.

With this, usage stats + health stats + security issues, you get a pretty complete view of your server activity.

Comment: Since OP wants to protect their website, IDS/IPS discussion should include Web Application Firewalls (WAF). In this case ModSecurity is the heavy favorite.

Comment: @user2320464: The OP did not asked *"How can I protect my website?"*, this would be an overwhelmingly broad question where WAF would be just a part of the equation, he asked for a standard way to store all received queries and to analyze them in order block offenders and generate statistics. WAF are positioned in front of the server *before* the requests are received, so they are not part of this. Moreover, you talk about ModSecurity which is an Apache-only module, the OP did not restrict his question to a single web server and actually uses Nginx according to its comments.

Comment: I agree this is a broad question and needs more specifics. Only wanted to point out that when protecting websites/web servers specifically, one should also include WAFs with IDS/IPS. ModSecurity supports lots of platforms now, even IIS!